# Overcoming ambiguity in antlr4?

Tags: antlr4

I have the grammar below, it's an extract out of something I am working on which is highlighting a problem I can't overcome.

In my grammar an expression is either a literal, which is a number or an expression "+" another expression. So I want to parse:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4
```

etc.

However my definition of a number means that it can have an optional sign e.g.:

`1`, `+1` or `-1`

So it's conceivable that I may need to parse:

`1 + +1` or `1 + -1`

What I am finding is that `1 + 1` (or bigger numbers) are fine.

What I am struggling to parse are inputs without spaces or with extra signs e.g.:

`1+2`

This causes real problems as the lexer picks up `+2` as a Number when actually I want `2` as the number and `+` to be picked up as the sign in the expression.

How do I get antlr4 to recognise the difference?

```
grammar example;

example : expression* EOF;

expression 
    :  expression '+' expression
    |  literal
    ;

literal : Number;

Number : Sign? Digits;

Sign : [-+];

Digits : Digit+;

Digit : [0-9];

WS : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete optional **Sign** lexem in the **Number** token. This way you will postpone processing of signs to parser stage, when you have more information about the context of the input. The idea here is to create unary operators for negation, minus sign (-) and plus sign (+) for keeping the number intact.

```
grammar example;

example : expression* EOF;

expression
    : ('+'|'-') expression # unaryOp
    | expression ('+'|'-') expression # binaryOp
    | Number # number
    ;

Number : [0-9]+;
WS : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip;
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's still relevant, but here goes:
Your expression rule seems faulty, it can not match on a "literal + literal" string, because it always expects an expression on the left.

Your rule should look something like:

```
expression:
literal + literal
| expression + literal;
```

Comment: It can match `literal + literal` since one of the sub-rules of `expression` is `literal`.

Comment: You are aware that this answer is over a year old, correct?

Comment: Yes. What is the connection between content and time here?